# PHP MySQL query statement problems

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to fix this PHP MySQL query all afternoon and am losing my mind! the following query works!:

```
$sql = "SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.channel, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified, c.image, 
        cg.name AS cgroup, CONCAT(o.payment_address_1, '<br>', o.payment_city, ', ', o.payment_zone, ' ', o.payment_postcode) AS address, o.telephone AS phone, o.email AS email,               
        (SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . 
        "') AS order_status FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c ON(o.customer_id=c.customer_id) LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description` 
        cg ON(c.customer_group_id=cg.customer_group_id)";
```

but when I try to add the following to it it breaks.

```
(SELECT action FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate_history h LEFT JOIN " . DB_prefix . "order od ON (h.customer_id = od.customer_id)),
```

I dont if Im writing it right. I've rewritten it, removed parts, tried to make as simple as possible, but I can't fix it. This is what I've been trying :

```
$sql = "SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.channel, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified, c.image, 
        cg.name AS cgroup, CONCAT(o.payment_address_1, '<br>', o.payment_city, ', ', o.payment_zone, ' ', o.payment_postcode) AS address, o.telephone AS phone, o.email AS email,
        (SELECT action FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate_history h LEFT JOIN " . DB_prefix . "order od ON (h.customer_id = od.customer_id)),             
        (SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . 
        "') AS order_status FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c ON(o.customer_id=c.customer_id) LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description` 
        cg ON(c.customer_group_id=cg.customer_group_id)";
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: You don't have any alias for the column. After the closing parentheses write something like `as action` see the others to see what I mean.

Comment: Two observations: calling a table 'order' is asking for trouble; what if there's a payment_address_2?

Comment: what's the status of *this* question? you've been comments and an answer, yet nothing from you.

Comment: @Strawberry *"calling a table 'order' is asking for trouble"* - Right you are and is unknown as to what's going on with the question.

Comment: Adam; if the question's a stale mate, it should be deleted. You realize that `order` is a MySQL reserved word, I hope you know that that needs special attention as your query *will* error out, as posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your new subquery you tried adding didn't have an alias.

```
SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.channel, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, 
   o.date_added, o.date_modified, c.image, cg.name AS cgroup, CONCAT(o.payment_address_1, '<br>', o.payment_city, ', ', o.payment_zone, ' ', o.payment_postcode) AS address, 
   o.telephone AS phone, o.email AS email,
    (SELECT action 
         FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate_history h 
         LEFT JOIN " . DB_prefix . "order od 
             ON (h.customer_id = od.customer_id)) AS donate_history,             
    (SELECT os.name 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os 
             WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . 
    "') AS order_status 
    FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o 
        LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c 
             ON(o.customer_id=c.customer_id) 
        LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description` cg 
             ON(c.customer_group_id=cg.customer_group_id)
```